# Pandas Grouped Cumulative Count with Condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas df with Year, UserID, and Points. I'm trying to derive the fourth column below - a running count of the number of consecutive years a user has 0 points or less per year.

Ex Df

| Year | UserID | Points | RunningCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 13 | 10 | 0 |
| 2011 | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 2012 | 13 | -5 | 1 |
| 2013 | 13 | 0 | 2 |
| 2014 | 13 | 4 | 0 |
| 2010 | 77 | -9 | 0 |
| 2011 | 77 | -1 | 1 |
| 2012 | 77 | 5 | 0 |
| 2013 | 77 | 0 | 0 |
| 2014 | 77 | -1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can create a group column for consecutive positive or negative points first and then do a `cumcount` by the group:

```
neg_group = df.Points.le(0).diff().ne(0).groupby(df.UserID).cumsum()

neg_group
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    1
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    3
Name: Points, dtype: int64

df.groupby([df.UserID, neg_group]).cumcount()
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is close! It's creating a cumulative sum for basically any streak that is <=0 but also streaks that are >0. How can I modify this to just look at the streaks <=0?

I can take the column you created and recreate it again (let's call it NonPosStreak) with .apply(lambda x: 0 if x.Points > 0 else x.NonPosStreak). This gets the desired outcome. Just wondering if there is another way. 

Thanks either way!

Comment: To keep non positive streak only, you can use chain a where clause to zero out positive streak. Basically `df.groupby([df.UserID, neg_group]).cumcount().where(df.Points <= 0, 0)`.